# Need regex for matching unquoted whole words excluding a list of set words

Tags: .net, regex

Given this exact string:

```
Name = "John" AND Country = "USA"
```

I want two matches returned:

```
Name
Country
```

I want to match all unquoted whole words *as long as* they are not in a short list of defined words (e.g. `AND`, `OR`)

This will be used in a .NET environment.

Comment: If you can match `ZipCode` from the string `Name = "John" AND Country = "USA"` then you are a magician :)

Comment: I've basically been trying to combine \b\w+\b with a negative form of ^" and "$  and failing miserably..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match any word consisting of alphanumeric and `_` characters that is not terminated by a `"`. Excluding the `|` delimited elements in the `(?! )`.

It should serve your purposes.

```
(?<!")\b(?!excludethis|andthis|andthisone|andthat|thistoo|AND)\w+\b(?!")
```

---

*Warning, this will match `Tome` and `and` in `Country = "Sao Tome and Principee"`*

Comment: I don’t think this will work if there's a space in the quoted word.  For example if the string is this:      Name = "John" AND Country = "United States"

Comment: `"United States"` isn't a quoted word, it's a quoted phrase so your question got more difficult. I've added a negative lookbehind as well, but it still won't work for `"Principe Sao Tome"`

Comment: thank you!  works great!  Seeing it the way you've coded it, it actually makes sense, too!   thanks again-

Comment: ah, I just realized your comment about the quoted phrase issue if it's more than 2 words (so that one doesn't begin or end with a quote).  it's still very close to what I want and I'm going to play around with it.  worst case I can handle it programmatically after the match is made.   definitely got me further along.  thanks again.

Comment: what if I were to replace all quoted phrases ".+?" with empty strings prior to applying your pattern?

Comment: Yeah, you could try something like that `"[^"]+?"` or if your quoted strings could have escaped quotes: `"(\\"|[^"])+?"`

Comment: replacing all quoted phrases with `"[^"]+?"` (shouldn't have any escaped quotes) and then applying your pattern (minus the now unneeded look-ahead/behind)    `\b(?!excludethis|andthis|andthisone|andthat|thistoo|AND)\w+\b`    seems to do the trick.   I just wish I could condense it down into one operation but at this point I'll take what I can get!  :)